# Profiling dotnet core in Linux and Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Is there any way to perform a CPU and memory profiling in Linux and Visual Studio Code for a dotnet core application?
Similar to the "Diagnostics Tools" of Visual Studio 2017

Comment: You should give a look to dotnet-trace

Answer (score 6):

> https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1647
>
> Q: So, Visual Studio has profiling tools to help you optimize your .Net
>   Core projects. I was wondering if this is possible to do on Linux or
>   macOS.
>
> REPLY: @doyouevensunbro, Visual Studio doesn't have any profiling tools that
>   work with .NET Core on Linux. At the current time, we recommend
>   collecting performance data on Linux using perf. Instructions are
>   available at
>   https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/linux-performance-tracing.md.
>
> We're also working on exposing a .NET-centric profiler using
>   functionality called EventPipe in CoreCLR. There's not much
>   documentation on the subject yet.

See also:

> [Profiling .NET Core app on
>   Linux](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/profiling-net-core-app-linux/)
>
> There’re multiple tools to use out there, but the basic toolkit for
>   profiling .NET Core app on Linux seems to be [perf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perf) utility along with
>   [lttng](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lttng) and perfcollect. Let’s have a look at all of them.

And:

[Bringing .NET application performance analysis to Linux](https://lttng.org/blog/2018/08/28/bringing-dotnet-perf-analysis-to-linux/)

Comment: I see that there is nothing so simple and graphic as the diagnostic tools of Visual Studio

Comment: To each his (or her) own.  Personally, I find the dotnet CLI a refreshing change from having to rely on GUIs ... For whatever it's worth, any code profiling you do in MSVS 2017 will probably also apply to the app's behavior under Linux or MacOS.  You can still *USE* MSVS profiling tools .. you just can't use them directly on non-Windows platforms.  Yet :)  'Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfcollect cannot be installed easily on WSL2 for now, we need to build perf tool from source. Welcome to stone age